# New name with same or new list?

Tags: python, list, object, reference

If I have `x=['f', 1]`, then `module.x = x`, would module.x be referencing x, or does it create a new list that references the objects inside x's list? If you get my question. This is in terms of like drawing  a picture of how Python executes.

Comment: What is `module`? Please give a complete minimal example.

Comment: Short answer is `module.x` is referencing to `x`. In other words, if you change `x` it will change `module.x` as well

Comment: @DYZ, I think he/she means a member variable of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we do:

```
x = ['f', 1]
```

1. It creates a list.
2. `x` gets assigned it's `reference`.

When we do:

```
module.x = x
```

`module.x` gets assigned the same reference.

So, a new list is `not` created.

---

Run this code to clearly understand it:

```
class Temp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None

x = ['f', 1]
print(id(x))    

temp = Temp()
temp.x = x

print(id(temp.x))

assert id(x) == id(temp.x)
```